Прекрасное далёко: do I need to capitalize any letters?

Слышу голос из (п/П)рекрасного (д/Д)алёка,
Голос утренний в серебряной росе...

This is a popular Russian song. Can I ask if I have to to capitalize anything here?
П in Прекрасное and/or Д in далёко.
It seems it's not a country. Or, rather, let me say: I am a rationalist and I do not know a country with such a name.

What if it's a city? A town? A village? A historic name of a place?

In 1984 Юрий Энтин (a poet) and Евгений Крылатов wrote this song for the film
«Гостья из будущего». So «прекрасное далёко» is (светлое будущее)  beautiful future. And it has nothing to do with capital letters
ПРЕКРАСНОЕ ДАЛЕКО
Муз. Е Крылатова, сл.Ю.Энтина
Слышу голос из прекрасного далека,
Голос утренний в серебряной росе.
Слышу голос,и манящая дорога
Кружит голову, как в детстве карусель.
Припев:
Прекрасное далеко,
Не будь ко мне жестоко,
Не будь ко мне жестоко,
Жестоко не будь.
От чистого истока,
В прекрасное далеко,
В прекрасное далеко,
Я начинаю путь.
https://www.kino-teatr.ru/kino/movie/sov/1493/song/

First of all, what you should do is find some Soviet publication of this song and see for yourself.
But, theoretically, Далёко should almost certainly be capitalized: there are lines that appeal to it, such as "Прекрасное Далёко, не будь ко мне жестоко". In this case it is customary to treat it as a first name grammatically. For example, in Russian translation of Le Petit Prince, the fox is referred to as Лис, whereas it doesn't seem to be the case in French (?).
We can't be sure about Прекрасное - maybe it is a part of the first name (a nickname of Прекрасное Далёко), but it is also plausible that it is just an adjective applied to Далёко so to not be capitalized.

На официальном сайте Крылатова:
http://www.krylatov.ru/pesni/pesni/muzyka-k-filmam/gostja-iz-buduschego/prekrasnoe-daleko
Слово "далёко" всегда пишется с маленькой буквы.
На официальном сайте Энтина:
http://www.entin.ru/nov_knigi/trehtomnik
"Прекрасное Далёко" написано именно так.  Слово "Далёко" пишется с заглавной буквы.
Я считаю, что, поскольку Энтин - автор слов, правильнее писать "Прекрасное Далёко", следуя авторской орфографии.
(Впрочем, у меня нет книг Энтина с текстами песен.)
